# R change character to equation that can be used by curve() function

Tags: r, plot, formula

I have the following character string

```
"x*3.55771902829131+x*-1.26223375202399+x*-0.486886610871284"
```

I would like to convert it to a form that can be passed to the curve function.

```
curve(x*3.55771902829131+x*-1.26223375202399+x*-0.486886610871284, add = TRUE)
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Kuba

Comment: Why do you have code as a character string that needs to be parsed? You should avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose in this situation you could use `parse`:

```r
str <- "x*3.55771902829131+x*-1.26223375202399+x*-0.486886610871284"
func <- as.function(c(alist(x =), parse(text = str)[[1]]))
curve(func)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Do you have any idea on why ```curve(expr=parse(text = str))``` fails? Isn't ```parse(text = str)``` an expression?

Comment: @peter861222 `curve` does non-standard evaluation. Read its documentation.

Comment: @peter861222 `curve` uses `substitute` to capture the argument passed to `expr`, so `parse(text = str)`  isn't actually evaluated into an expression. Rather, it is captured as a call. Although `curve` works with calls, the call has to be to a function that takes an argument called `x`, otherwise it throws the error you can see.

Comment: Very informative! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not recommended but you still can try `eval` + `str2lang`

```
s <- "x*3.55771902829131+x*-1.26223375202399+x*-0.486886610871284"
eval(str2lang(sprintf("curve(%s)", s)))
```